# How to discover (possibly approximate) dependencies between SML source files?

Tags: compilation, dependencies, sml

I have software written in Standard ML (henceforth SML) which I'd like to make portable across three compilers.

- [Standard ML of New Jersey](http://www.smlnj.org) is the easiest, as their Compilation Manager does the dependency analysis for you.
- [MLton](http://www.mlton.org) uses a similar format to SML/NJ, but it requires that files be listed in dependency order, similar to Unix libraries.
- [Moscow ML](http://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/mosml.html) uses an ordinary Makefile, but requires that dependencies be listed on the command line (and so ideally go into the Makefile).

What I'd like to do is take a list of SML source files and discover dependencies between files.  Here are the ways I've tried and failed:

- The SML/NJ Compilation Manager produces a dependency graph, but it is not a graph of files.  Instead it contains a big collection of undocumented compiler internals.  Turning that into a dependency graph on *files* has been tried since at least 2009; nobody has done it.
- If I once get files into dependency order, I can get def/use information, which includes source code position, from MLton.  So if I find a partial solution that gets files in order for MLton, and I can use that to get a complete solution.

I'm looking for ideas along the lines of simple tools that would give approximate answers.  My code has two special properties:

- It never uses `open`.
- Every top-level definition is a structure, functor, or signature definition.

It seems to me that in this situation, a simple syntactic tool might be able to find external dependencies of a file.  But I don't quite know how to write one.

Ideas?

Comment: @andreas-rossberg This one has your name on it.

Answer (score 1):

In the MLton repository, there is a `cm2mlb` tool that will convert a `.cm` file into an MLB file (util/cm2mlb of the git repo).  If you put all of your files into a `.cm` file you should be able to use this to generate an MLB file that will be in dependency order.

Comment: Looks perfect; I will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.sml.smlnj/612), which is asking a similar question, I was able to write a small program that *worked for me* (I copied the produced list of file names, pasted it inside an .mlb file, and MLton was able to compile my little project). So, I can't guarantee anything, but it's probably a good start. Hope it helps.

#### sources.cm

```
group
  structure Deps
is
  $/basis.cm
  $/pgraph.cm
  $smlnj/cm.cm

  deps.sml
```

#### deps.sml

```
structure Deps =
struct
  structure PG = PortableGraph

  fun list () =
    let
      fun println s = print (s ^ "\n")

      fun extractFiles def =
        case def of
          PG.DEF { rhs = PG.COMPILE { src, ... }, ... } => SOME (#1 src)
        | _ => NONE

      val PG.GRAPH { defs, ... } =
        (* Replace "sources.cm" with your project's .cm file path. *)
        #graph (valOf (CM.Graph.graph "sources.cm"))

      val files = List.mapPartial extractFiles defs
    in
      List.app println files
    end
end
```